# InputSelect not working on client side blazor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, api, blazor

I'm trying to code a form to insert Objects into a database (via api POST petition), everything works fine but InputSelect is not working. It shows me the data but doesn't sends the selected option when I click the submit button

The form code:

```
@using ClinicaVistaalegre.Shared.Models
@inject HttpClient Http

<EditForm Model="@Cita" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
    <h3>Crear cita</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Motivo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Motivo
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="Motivo" class="form-control" placeholder="Motivo"
                       @bind-Value="Cita.Motivo" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="FechaHora" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Fecha y Hora
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @*<inp @bind=Cita.FechaHora @bind:format="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm" type="datetime-local"/>*@
            <InputDate id="FechaHora" class="form-control" placeholder="FechaHora"
                       @bind-Value="Cita.FechaHora" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="MedicoId" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Contacto
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="Cita.MedicoId" class="form-control">
                @foreach (Medico m in medicos)
                {
                    <option value="@m.Id">@m.Apellidos</option>
                }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="PacienteId" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
        Paciente
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <InputText id="Paciente" class="form-control" placeholder="Paciente"
                   @bind-Value="Cita.PacienteId" />
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">@TextoBoton</button>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Medico[]? medicos;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() => 
        medicos = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Medico[]>("api/Medicos");

    [Parameter] public Cita Cita { get; set; } = new Cita();
    [Parameter] public String TextoBoton { get; set; } = "Guardar";
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
}
```

Container code:

```
@page "/creacitas"
@using ClinicaVistaalegre.Shared.Models
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavMan


<PageTitle>Citas</PageTitle>

<h1>Crear cita</h1>

<FormularioCita TextoBoton="Crear cita" OnValidSubmit="@CrearCita" Cita="@cita"/>

@code {
    Cita cita = new Cita();

    async Task CrearCita(){
        //var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cita);
        //await Http.PostAsync("api/Citas", new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        //await Http.PostAsync("api/Citas", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json)));
        //UriHelper.
        //var addItem = new TodoItem { Name = newItemName, IsComplete = false };
        
        HttpResponseMessage mensaje = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Citas", cita);

        if (mensaje.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            NavMan.NavigateTo("fetchcitas");
        }

    }
}
```

Cita and Medico Model:

```
public class Cita
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PacienteId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public Paciente? Paciente { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MedicoId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public Medico? Medico { get; set; }

        public string? Motivo { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaHora { get; set; }
    }

public class Medico
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Especialidad { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public List<Cita> Citas { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public List<Mensaje> Mensajes { get; set; }
    }
```

Chrome browser debug tool give me this error:

```
    blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ClinicaVistaalegre.Client.Shared.FormularioCita.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_8(RenderTreeBuilder __builder3) in C:\Users\santanitaxx1050\Desktop\ClinicaVistaalegre\ClinicaVistaalegre\Client\Shared\FormularioCita.razor:line 32
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(Int32 sequence, RenderFragment fragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputSelect`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
window.Module.s.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

But the compiled page has the correct option value:

```
<option value="b04efe29-a306-40b1-8799-41b99b215a69">sanchez luque</option>
```

[Issue picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcaWb.png)

I tried removing  and the error above doesn't appear but the POST petition doesn't get the InputSelect data and tries to insert an object with MedicoId null field

Edit: Maybe an InputSelect parsing problem???

Edit 2: If i change Medicos[] to List I don't have the first error but when I try to submit it appears me like the value it's not correct due to the

Edit 3:

I managed to make an almost successfull api petition with enet answer and removing DataAnnotationsValidator in EditForm but I have this incomplete object:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "pacienteId": "1d49f54a-91cb-4980-8983-9a70bd1c668d",
  "paciente": null,
  "medicoId": null,
  "medico": null,
  "motivo": "pruebacreate",
  "fechaHora": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

paciente and medico should be null, that's not the problem, the problem here is that medicoId is null and it has no sense because it shows the options and values correctly

Comment: What I suspect is that the `medicos` is not initialized with value before receive value from API. So it hits NRE in the `@foreach`. You can try to initialize the `medicos` by `List<Medico> medicos = new List<Medico>();` (Prefer use `List` instead of `array` as for array you need to define the size when initialize). Or you can add `if` statement that wrap `@foreach` to check `medicos` is not null. `@if (medicos != null) {  foreach(...) { ... } }`

Comment: I tried this but submit didn't received the selected option

Comment: Anyway, did you try to print out the `cita` data before sending the request and see `MedicoId` has any value?

Comment: MedicoId has null value at this point, that's the problem

Comment: What about to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead to post all your whole business code? A simple sample that someone easily can copy-paste and run. Sure an MRE will help a lot of people with the same issue, but your code is tedious to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to only add an empty value option into InputSelect

### InputSelect:

```
<InputSelect id="Medico" class="form-control" placeholder="Medico" @bind-Value="@Cita.MedicoId">
            <option value="">---</option>
            @if(medicos!=null){
                foreach (Medico m in medicos)
            {
                <option value="@m.Id">@m.Apellidos</option>
            }
            }
        </InputSelect>
```

It is finally working!